# Windows single-user SCM with grep feature?

Tags: windows, version-control, grep

For single-user development, I like [Fossil](http://www.fossil-scm.org/) because it's a single EXE and has a lot of features.

However, at this point, it doesn't have a grep feature to search for code in the repository. The only way is to write a script with a loop to successively check out each revision and grep through the work files.

Is there another small, good SCM (for Windows) that does support grep to avoid checking out revisions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not so small, but good - Mercurial (in form of [TortoiseHG](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/)). It **has** power [grep](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/grep).